# Force an error on a field with Parsley.js

Tags: parsley.js

I'm using parsley (1.x) for the client-side validation of a form. I need to force an error on a certain field after the server-side validation.

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="field1" >
<input type="text" name="field2" >
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

I've tried the methods described in this page but it doesn't work:
https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/111

Anyone can help me?

Thx

Comment: Can you please clarify your requirements. Are you using JavaScript? You want an error "after server-side validation" - presumably the server-side code detects an error and re-displays the page, which you want the error displayed on. How will the server indicate the error?

Comment: It makes an ajax call that return a JSon with the server response. I've already filtered the results and I'm able to find the input names that contains errors. 

I'd like to have something like this:
$("#inputWithError").parsley('addError','Error message');

Comment: Can you use `parsley-remote="http://yoururl.com"` for your ajax call? See the v1 documentation: http://parsleyjs.github.io/Parsley-1.x/documentation.html

Answer (score 5):

In version 2.4.3 you can do this:

```
$('#fieldName').parsley().addError('forcederror', {message: 'My error message.', updateClass: true});
```

Source: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-ui-for-javascript

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to resolve this issue writing a new validation rule that return alwais an invalid field.

```
forcevalidation : function() {
                    return {
                        validate : function(val, elem, self) {
                            return false;
                        },
                        priority : 32
                    };
                },
```

When I receive the ajax response I add the validator to the affected field and then I remove it:

```
                affectedInput.attr('parsley-forcevalidation', true);
                affectedInput.attr('parsley-error-message', errorMessage);
                affectedInput.parsley('destroy');
                affectedInput.parsley('validate');
                affectedInput.removeAttr('parsley-forcevalidation');
```